# execute a slider script on a div, only after it is populated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

For the slider script to work it requires a specific html structure like this :

```
<div class="the-carousel">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I have only this:

```
<div id="courseList" class="the-carousel"></div>
```

And then the rest of the content I want to populate from an array.

After the user clicks on a image/button, a modal pops up with a list of 7 questions and answers.

The problem is , even though I put the slider script last,and inside the click function , it still loads before the any array data is injected . and therefore is not creating a slider , because it only sees one div.

here are the modal html and the script that injects the array...

```
<div class="workersQA">
    <div class="workers" id="man1" data-modalworkers="first">
        <h3>click</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="workers" id="man2" data-modalworkers="second">
        <h3>click</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- the modal html -->

<div id="modal" data-opened="false">
    <div class="background">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="modal">
                <div class="QA">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <span class="close">close</span>
                            <div id="tit_wrapper"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <h3 class="ques"></h3>
                        <div id="courseList"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the js:

```
(function($) {
    var selectedWorkers = [];
    var dataSourceWorkers = [{
        name: "first",
        subtit: ".worker1-ques",
        title: "worker1",
        image: "man1card.png",

        courses: [{
            id: "1-1",
            ques: "question number one?",
            answer: "answer number one."
        }, {
            id: "1-2",
            ques: "question number 2?",
            answer: "answer number 2"
        }, {
            id: "1-3",
            ques: "question number 3?",
            answer: "answer number 3."
        }, {
            id: "1-4",
            ques: "question number 4",
            answer: "answer number 4"
        }]
    }, {
        name: "second",
        subtit: ".worker2-ques",
        title: "worker2",
        image: "man2card.png",
        courses: [{
            id: "2_1",
            ques: "question number one?",
            answer: "answer number one."
        }, {
            id: "2-2",
            ques: "question number 2?",
            answer: "answer number 2"
        }, {
            id: "2-3",
            ques: "question number 3?",
            answer: "answer number 3."
        }, {
            id: "2-4",
            ques: "question number 4",
            answer: "answer number 4"
        }]
    }];

    $("[data-modalworkers]").click(function() {
        var topic = $(this).data("modalworkers");
        var data = dataSourceWorkers.filter(function(item) {
            return item.name == topic;
        })[0];
        slug = data.name;
        if (data) {
            $(".workersQA #tit_wrapper").html(
                '<img src="images/' +
                data.pic +
                '"/>' +
                "<h2>" +
                data.title +
                "</h2>" +
                '<p class="job_desc">' +
                data.subtit +
                "</p>"
            );
            $(".workersQA #modalTitle").removeClass();
            $(".workersQA #modalTitle").addClass(data.name);
            $(".workersQA #courseList").html("");
            data.courses.forEach(function(course) {
                // create div
                var div = $(
                    '<div id="' +
                    course.id +
                    '"><h3>' +
                    course.ques +
                    '</h3><div><div class="cbp-content"></div><p>' +
                    course.answer +
                    "</p></div></div>"
                ).get(0);
                // add QA to html
                $(".workersQA #courseList").append(div);

            });
        }
        $("#modal").attr("data-opened", true);
        $("#modal").show();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: you need to initialize slider after foreach loop `data.courses.forEach(function(course) {`

Comment: One quick tip: anytime you're grabbing an ID via jQuery, you don't need to query anything else. `$(".workersQA #tit_wrapper")` is wasteful and potentially leads to performance issues. Just use `$("#tit_wrapper")`

Comment: thank you Mahesh , I have tried but still doesn't solve this , where exactly will you put this code "  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
"

Comment: you are right mccambridge!